# Android Intent Management

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know how android manages Intents (especially Action Intents) and where I can find the code that handles this inside the OS.

To be more precise, I would like to find the portion of code that selects the application to launch when an action Intent is received.

Thanks...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK

Comment: are you looking for Intent.class?

Comment: What you are asking about is 'Intent resolution' and it is pretty well documented at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires If you want to find the source code, I would start with the `PackageManager` methods that start with `resolve...` as those methods do exactly what you are asking about (although they probably call other methods to actually do it)